# How to convert python file into exe which has multiple other files with it?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to use Pyinstaller to make an exe file of my program but my program involves images in another folder within the directory of the py script.
I'm not sure how to add the folder of photos to the exe file as well because if I do make the main python file into an exe I get an error saying it cannot find/access the images.

This is what my folder looks like, the icons folder is where all the images are and the player.py file is the main file:
[image]

Is there a specfic command I should use for pyinstaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--add-data` and `--add-binary` flags will come in handy here. From the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html):

```
--add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>
    Additional non-binary files or folders to be added to the executable. The
    path separator is platform specific, `os.pathsep` (which is ; on Windows
    and : on most unix systems) is used. This option can be used multiple
    times.
```

So in our example, we can perhaps do:

```
> pyinstaller player.py --add-data Icons:<destination-directory-name>
```

where `destination-directory-name` is the directory name you are actually using in the script. I imagine that it'll also be `Icons`, but it can be anything.